# Using python variable with execjs objects

Tags: javascript, python, execjs

I am doing some web scraping and need to parse multiple javascript objects to list their specific property. Problem I am facing is that execjs is treating my JS object as a string.  Is there any way I can go around it?  Here is my sample code (real code has a LOT more properties).

```
import execjs
car1 = "{type:'Mazda', model:5, color:'white'}"
attr = execjs.compile("""
    function car_type(x) {var temp = x; return temp.type;}
""")

print(attr.call("car_type",car1))
```

As a result I get 'None'. I used 'typeof' to identify my 'temp' variable and it is 'string' not object :|...

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your var car1 from string to python dict and your code will work fine

```
car1 = {"type":'Mazda', "model":5, "color":'white'}
```